# IIS 7 Application Pool Advanced Settings is missing enable32bitAppOnWin64 option

Tags: iis, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, 32-bit

I'm hoping there is a simple reason for this, but I can't find it anywhere.
I am looking at 2 separate servers, both have IIS 7, one is Windows Server 2008 R2 Version 7.5.7600.16385 the second is Windows 7 Professional Version 7.5.7600.16385.
The first had a option on the AppPool settings to enable32bitAppOnWin64, but the second does not.
Does anyone know what the default functionality will be on the second, as well as how to change it, and why it does not show up when it is the same build of IIS, but only a different server OS?
Thanks

Comment: did you get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're running Windows 7 which isn't 64 bit. You can check this by going to:

> `Control Panel > System`

Then take a look at the `System Type:` field.

Comment: Yes it was on a 32 bit server, I should have thought about that.